# Problem with NetBeans 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: netbeans

I was working in win7, and I just got sick of windows. So I installed 14.04 LTS and NetBeans today. Opened it and start new project, several times. Won't create new project, won't do nothing.

At one point, the app had to be killed. So, I'm totally new to Ubuntu and Linux and need help. I couldn't find answer that could save my problem.

Comment: Try to delete Netbeans and re-install it.

Comment: Tried, now it won't launch it.

Comment: try this in the terminal: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall netbeans`

Comment: Nothing. No response. Just opens the NetBeans and no red loading indicator is filling. After few seconds is closed, and that's it. I hope you understand my English. :)

Comment: Well, I solved the problem. I re-installed NetBeans, but I downloaded from their site .sh file, and installed it using the terminal. It works. Thank you for your time.
This is what I used: " chmod +x netbeans-8.0-linux.sh",
"./netbeans-8.0-linux.sh".

Comment: I have had the same problem, solved it by removing OpenJDK and the installing Java from Oracle then downloaded Netbeans 8 from Oracle and installed that, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I reinstalled NetBeans, but I downloaded from their site .sh file, and installed it using the terminal. It works. 
This is what I used:

chmod +x netbeans-8.0-linux.sh

./netbeans-8.0-linux.sh

Comment: Are you saying it was installed with apt-get install previously ?
And the download from http://netbeans.org worked ?

Comment: it worked for me but without install it using terminal as it was the problem with me

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're hitting [bug 1274469](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnb-javaparser-java/+bug/1274469); the `libnb-javaparser-java` package is newer than the netbeans installation.

The fix is to manually downgrade your version of `libnb-javaparser-java`, to match the version of netbeans that's installed. You can do this with:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libn/libnb-javaparser-java/libnb-javaparser-java_7.0.1-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnb-javaparser-java_7.0.1-1_all.deb
```

then restart netbeans.

Comment: Problem is solved. Thank you for your effort. Had problems with PC so I couldn't answer you earlier.

Comment: This is the solution. tanx

Answer (score 1):

Install the Latest Package of Java first. Make sure to read the Netbeans installation instructions completely. They will mention what version(s) of Java are supported for the version of Netbeans you are downloading.

Next make sure the netbeans download is extracted (if zipped) and made executable (important). Then open a command line terminal (CTRL - ALT - T). Make sure to execute the sh file as sudo. This will ensure that the Netbeans install will be able to find your version(s) of Java installed.

sudo sh netbeans-8.0.1-php-linux.sh

Answer (score 1):

When starting from shell got the following message:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0
```

in this case this might be the solution:

```
netbeans --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

or any other jdk7 happens to be installed.

If so then to make it more permanent one can edit following lines in /etc/netbeans.conf:

```
# Default location of JDK, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir>:
#netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
```

or to do it in user space edit .desktop or menu file and/or add alias to shell's rc file.

Comment: this is the right answer for nb 7.0.1, tx!

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you getting any error messages?

I believe this issue can be related to permissions. Have you tried to run the program as root?

```
sudo netbeans
```

or

```
sudo netbeans-7.0.1
```

Comment: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0

This is what is shown in terminal.